# Problems with \DeclareSortingScheme for @misc documents in Biblatex

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I apologize for the probably quite simple questions, but somehow I struggle to find an answer in the docs and online.

I would like to have a separate bibliography for the UN Documents I am using, which I defined (according to the OSCOLA style) like this:

```
@misc{sc955,
    institution = "UNSC",
    instrument_no = "Res 955",
    date = "1994-11-08",
    doc_no = "UN Doc S/RES/955",
    entrysubtype = "undoc",
    keywords = "undoc"
}
```

I would like to sort them by the institution, followed by the instrument number. I tried the following:

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{un-res}{
    \sort{ \field{institution} }
    \sort{ \field{instrument_no} }
} %(in the preamble)

\printbibliography[keyword=undoc, sorting=un-res, title={UN Documents}]
```

I don't get any error messages, but the sorting seems rather random. What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think I'd need more data to be get this right. But (1) I think you are going to have trouble sorting fields that contain letters as well as numbers numerically ("Res 23" will come after "Res 1111" ...) and (2) I think your field for sorting purposes should be "number" not "instrument_no", because IIRC the latter is an alias for the former.

Comment: You are right. I have been thinking in human logic, not in computer logic when it came to the sorting... I guess I will have to sort it by date then. Thanks!